# Como inserir dados agrupados de uma tabela para outra SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela 'ponto', com as colunas (id, pis, data, hora), que registram a entrada e saída de um produto('pis').
Queria agrupar em uma outra tabela, onde os dados, pis e data, sejam iguais agrupe todos os dados 'hora' sejam agrupados em uma única coluna.
Ex
Tabela 1

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| id    | pis          | data        | hora     |
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 1     | 12113879222  | 2018-02-02  | 07:21:00 |
| 2     | 12113879222  | 2018-02-02  | 11:59:00 |
| 3     | 21056646219  | 2018-02-02  | 07:32:00 | 
| 4     | 21056646219  | 2017-05-17  | 12:01:00 |
```

Para tabela 2

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| id    | pis          | data        | hora1    | hora2    |
+-------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 1     | 12113879222  | 2018-02-02  | 07:21:00 | 11:59:00 |
| 3     | 21056646219  | 2018-02-02  | 07:32:00 |          |
| 4     | 21056646219  | 2017-05-17  | 12:01:00 |          |
```

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você escreveu. Tente formatar sua pergunta e descrever melhor seu problema. Use de pontuação e gramática para escrever e antes de postar leia. Se você entender, clique em Salvar. Assim poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Cara o que voce quer fazer é algo bem complexo, qual a necessidade de fazer isto?

ve se este link te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/q/12643117

Comment: Qual SQL? Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, PostGreSQL?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade - MySQL

Comment: @DiegoSouza - Eu reescrevi, acho que agora tenha ficado mais claro

Comment: Só agrupar seria fácil e poderia fazer um `select..into` ou `insert...select` pra gerar a nova tabela, mas quebrar a hora em colunas requer recursos como *pivot table* por exemplo. O problema é que você não sabe quantos colunas de horas terão certo? Dessa forma fica bem inviável fazer isso

Comment: E as colunas horas são dinamicas? ou pode ser uma coluna só com as horas separadas por vírgula? MySQL Não possui um operador PIVOT nativo. https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 0):

Pensei em um método aqui bem tranquilo, você vai agrupar e selecionar o `MIN` do campo hora e o `MAX`, fazer um `case` para quando o `MIN` e o `MAX` forem iguais trazer nulo.

Aí é só fazer uma recursiva para trazer o id batendo com a maior data e inserir na nova tabela.

Segue código em SQL Server 2012

```
create table teste
(
id numeric, 
pis numeric, 
data date, 
hora datetime
)

create table teste_pronto
(
id numeric, 
pis numeric, 
data date, 
hora1 datetime,
hora2 datetime
)

insert teste values (1,1211,'2018-02-02','07:21');
insert teste values (2,1211,'2018-02-02','11:59');
insert teste values (3,2105,'2018-02-02','07:32');
insert teste values (4,2105,'2018-05-17','07:21')

With TBL 
as
(
Select pis,data,min(hora)hora1, 
Case 
When min(hora) = max(hora)
Then null
Else max(hora)
End Hora2
from teste
group by pis,data
)
insert teste_pronto
Select T2.id,T1.* from TBL T1 inner join Teste T2
on T1.pis = T2.pis and T2.data = T2.data and T1.hora1 = T2.hora


Select * from teste_pronto
```

OBS: só funcionará se tiver apenas dois horários, caso tenha mais ele vai trazer o menor e o maior.

Comment: Creio que este código deve funcionar no Mysql, caso não funcione esse site aqui convert http://www.sqlines.com/online

Answer (score 0):

O que você está buscando é um GROUP BY associado com as funções SUBSTRING_INDEX e GROUP_CONCAT. No MySQL, você terá algo assim:

```js
SELECT id, pis, data,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 1) AS hora1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 2) AS hora2
FROM tabela
GROUP BY pis, data;
```

Caso você queira mais de duas colunas para "hora", basta definir no código, lembrando de mudar o argumento referente ao número de vezes que deverá ser buscado o delimitador antes da extração pela função SUBSTRING_INDEX para cada nova coluna. Um exemplo geral:

```js
SELECT id, pis, data,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 1) AS hora1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 2) AS hora2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 3) AS hora3,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", 4) AS hora4,
       ...,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hora ORDER BY hora ASC), ",", N) AS horaN
FROM tabela
GROUP BY pis, data;
```

---

Apenas um aviso: o GROUP_CONCAT possui limite máximo de 1024 caracteres, que pode ser aumentado utilizando o comando:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = val;
```

para mudança apenas na sessão ou

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = val;
```

para mudança global; "val" é o valor (inteiro) que você escolher.